# How to prevent specific GitLab CI stage from being seen in merge requests?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been trying to prevent a stage (**x-apply**) from gitlab-ci to be seen from merge requests.
It should only be seen when the merge request is pushed to master or when there is a direct push to the master but it always throws an error saying;

> 'x-apply' job needs 'x-validate' job, but 'x-validate' is not in any previous stage

Here is my gitlab-ci;

```
x-validate:
  extends: .x-validate
  stage: build_and_publish_image
  tags:
    - x
  needs: [ ]
  rules:
    - changes:
        - x/y/z.yml
        - .gitlab-ci.yml

x-apply:
  extends: .x
  stage: infra
  tags:
    - x
  needs:
    - x-validate
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"'
      when: manual
    - changes:
        - x/y/z.yml
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

I tried to add this `rules` but it is not working.

How can I prevent this `x-apply` job to be seen only from merge requests?

Answer (score 0):

`x-validate` runs in all cases there there are changes to the mentioned files and `x-apply` runs when merged to master or directly pushed to master.

```yaml
x-validate:
  extends: .x-validate
  stage: build_and_publish_image
  tags:
    - x
  needs: [ ]
  rules:
    - changes:
        - x/y/z.yml
        - .gitlab-ci.yml

x-apply:
  extends: .x
  stage: infra
  tags:
    - x
  needs:
    - x-validate
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master"
      when: manual
      changes:
        - x/y/z.yml
        - .gitlab-ci.yml
      allow_failure: false
```